# How do I prevent a subreport from rendering over the top of other elements?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a master report that contains three sub-reports, named "vehicleListSubReport.jrxml", "locoSubreport.jrxml", and "crewSubreport.jrxml" Their datasources are the fields "vehicleReport", "locoReport" and "crewReport" respectively, which are all objects of type JRDataSource.

I am having a few problems, but I feel that they may have a single root cause, hence why I am asking about them all in the same question. Firstly, the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="X2010" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="25640552-4299-40b4-8655-a64e83b16458">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="trainNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="crewReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="trainType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="origin" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dangerousGoods" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="outOfGauge" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="trainDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="approvedLength" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="destination" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="specialLoad" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="submittedBy" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="submittedAtDateTime" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="fax" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numberOfVehicles" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="tonnesHauled" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tonnesGross" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="totalLength" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="locoReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="vehicleReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="railOperatorName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="submitter" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="consistLocation" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/15)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/5)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="107" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="80" y="0" width="472" height="62" uuid="b89a83c9-c1a2-4ab6-85a2-88ba23795dd3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[X20.10 Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="1" y="1" width="552" height="2" uuid="f93f01ef-7224-41b8-a330-380bec4336d6"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="20c60332-1cff-4218-bfce-57cec3e447dd"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="220" width="595" height="45" uuid="4f24664e-5df0-4326-9b95-9939f93c48d4"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{crewReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["crewSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="110c9328-d33c-4c0a-86e5-7f4ebe669b4f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="554" height="30" uuid="efaedffc-7d27-40f0-acc1-71797d91472c"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Details]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="91493735-ab12-4068-9583-9edbbac7ca35"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Type:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="a3e483b0-59c4-494c-ad36-1ea30eb4c5f5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Origin]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="f5f23f73-3bdb-4b12-b9ec-d1946d1d249c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dangerous Goods:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="49aebc16-13db-4842-bb0f-23eac8f693a4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Out of Gauge:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="ff7d87fc-1087-4edf-b1ed-454ff8ae94f8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="7f109b0f-f4f4-48af-9a13-909b766dbd3c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{origin}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="67f7fd28-1cee-402d-8a35-523058ab5061"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dangerousGoods} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="82586e0e-b6a7-43cf-9b1f-a12612396909"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{outOfGauge} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="94651700-a070-400e-a206-fd09170cf797"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="380" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="2ea29a18-1d85-4a23-b9f6-17459ceafe0d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="3ffe5495-6b91-424b-b652-c48c72b39a8f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Approved Length:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="68bcc4c2-d6c0-426b-979c-c70bbd1c550c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Destination:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="83e83257-d581-4fdd-8955-ef281357aaae"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Special Load:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="0f1b2cf0-73a3-4106-904a-8a28b7717909"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approvedLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="7a006853-a10a-4759-889f-b9848a59d79b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{destination}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="521136d0-a51f-4ca1-bdce-6d0ed1cd5c76"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{specialLoad} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="36b52f46-6f49-4c75-88d0-27a221bc62ec"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedBy}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="2cad93ef-d94f-4479-93e7-7a232023dace"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Submitted By:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="90474202-ce8b-4657-bad1-71edc8557335"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Phone:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="20d6f136-62e4-4332-9098-3355896ff4af"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phone}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
                <reportElement x="380" y="50" width="174" height="20" uuid="540bcba3-93ee-4877-b5a8-6f58db7c7398"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedAtDateTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="50" width="100" height="20" uuid="957ce926-9636-4625-b91f-78ecd3b8a200"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Submitted At:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="70" width="100" height="20" uuid="d8cf6e8b-9664-4012-b51d-6cdea49faf22"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Fax:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="70" width="174" height="20" uuid="cc95ebda-f955-4eaf-9314-45e4a56c4fde"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fax}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="554" height="50" uuid="f7c297a9-e14e-44de-8769-5d483cfe4863"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Consist for " + $F{railOperatorName} + " submitted by " + $F{submitter} + "\nConsist Location: " + $F{consistLocation}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="50" y="330" width="130" height="20" uuid="4f470a33-ef93-425d-951e-e53642df7771"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{locoReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["locoSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="460" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="f182c7db-f00f-4107-bc33-93b30faf11a9"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="c5f34099-ac0e-4634-9398-a96f93c052f6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesHauled}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="330" width="80" height="20" uuid="824478e7-fc00-4d16-8a39-6355baf4bc61"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Gross:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="e0bc266a-56f2-4246-bea6-f31c4718046d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Hauled:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="330" width="80" height="20" uuid="74e9ef61-e6e0-45fa-9966-9950c2f5a1e0"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesGross}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="100" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="86833b59-3fe2-4c50-8d8e-18d80e082f75"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberOfVehicles}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="330" width="40" height="20" uuid="c08f0b3c-0ddf-4cbb-b377-1f48b80fa383"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Locos:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="310" width="90" height="20" uuid="6a4a5d4b-5762-45d2-b54f-2167af8da5f8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Number Vehicles:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="270" width="551" height="35" uuid="53e5c946-8e6d-44fa-8715-f193d224b489"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Summary]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="370" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="31012f66-602d-4892-82f4-d1187915046e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total Length:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="360" width="595" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="Group1" uuid="8e2dbcb5-3c3f-4bb5-a606-39f6f2e8656a"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["vehicleListSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="6" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="2" uuid="447d20b2-f65e-42ee-b2a8-69632882c668"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="1" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="24b6cb4b-7cad-4abd-a159-cc5cc11896db"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="533" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="5463547b-d0a6-440d-baa9-9b1dcce760bf"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="453" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="17310c63-a8e1-4f36-aad6-1b37346d27f6"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="340aeee4-0582-45c2-9fbf-f1250cba3f8a"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

First problem: The crewSubreport has other report elements below it, including the other two sub-reports. If there are multiple records in this sub-report, it renders on top of the elements below it, including the other sub-reports.

Second problem: The data text fields below the crewSubreport are rendering (although with the subreport rendering on top of them), however, the static text boxes with the labels "Train Summary", "Number Vehicles:", "Tonnes Hauled:", "Total Length:", "Locos:", and "Tonnes Gross:" are not rendering, and I not yet able to determine why.

Third problem: Similar to the first problem, the locoSubreport is rendering into the space occupied by the vehicleListSubreport.

How do I fix these issues?

EDIT: Posting the following to illustrate the issues I'm having with the only answer so far:

[image]

In the memory usage and CPU usage graphs, the small peaks on the left are me running the report I designed. The rest of the graph after that is what happens when I run the report designed in the answer. It continues like this until the garbage collector seems to give up and kills the thread. Generating this report is the only thing the program is doing at this time. Using the VisualVM to force the JVM to perform a full garbage collection does not reclaim any memory. It would appear to me that there is a problem in Jasper Reports when using positionType="Float", and I need a solution that does not trigger this problem.

Comment: I have posted the same question on the Jaspersoft site here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824696/how-do-i-prevent-subreport-rendering-over-top-other-elements#comment-806263 . So far the suggestion to put each subreport in it's own detail band works, except I seem to only have a choice between having each detail band on it's own page, or not having each record on it's own page. I need each record on it's own page, and all the detail bands on the one page (unless it's too long for the page of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (everything belove first sub report is in a frame so it might be less cpu intensive to move them all together):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="X2010" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="25640552-4299-40b4-8655-a64e83b16458">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="trainNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="crewReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="trainType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="origin" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dangerousGoods" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="outOfGauge" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="trainDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="approvedLength" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="destination" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="specialLoad" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="submittedBy" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="phone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="submittedAtDateTime" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="fax" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numberOfVehicles" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="tonnesHauled" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tonnesGross" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="totalLength" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="locoReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="vehicleReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
    <field name="railOperatorName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="submitter" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="consistLocation" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/15)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/5)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="107" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="80" y="0" width="472" height="62" uuid="b89a83c9-c1a2-4ab6-85a2-88ba23795dd3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[X20.10 Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="5" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="1" y="1" width="552" height="2" uuid="f93f01ef-7224-41b8-a330-380bec4336d6"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="20c60332-1cff-4218-bfce-57cec3e447dd"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="220" width="595" height="45" uuid="4f24664e-5df0-4326-9b95-9939f93c48d4"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{crewReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["crewSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="110c9328-d33c-4c0a-86e5-7f4ebe669b4f"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="554" height="30" uuid="efaedffc-7d27-40f0-acc1-71797d91472c"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Details]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="91493735-ab12-4068-9583-9edbbac7ca35"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Type:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="a3e483b0-59c4-494c-ad36-1ea30eb4c5f5"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Origin]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="f5f23f73-3bdb-4b12-b9ec-d1946d1d249c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dangerous Goods:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="49aebc16-13db-4842-bb0f-23eac8f693a4"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Out of Gauge:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="ff7d87fc-1087-4edf-b1ed-454ff8ae94f8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainType}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="7f109b0f-f4f4-48af-9a13-909b766dbd3c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{origin}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="67f7fd28-1cee-402d-8a35-523058ab5061"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dangerousGoods} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="82586e0e-b6a7-43cf-9b1f-a12612396909"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{outOfGauge} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="94651700-a070-400e-a206-fd09170cf797"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Train Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="380" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="2ea29a18-1d85-4a23-b9f6-17459ceafe0d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="3ffe5495-6b91-424b-b652-c48c72b39a8f"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Approved Length:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="68bcc4c2-d6c0-426b-979c-c70bbd1c550c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Destination:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="83e83257-d581-4fdd-8955-ef281357aaae"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Special Load:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="0f1b2cf0-73a3-4106-904a-8a28b7717909"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approvedLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="7a006853-a10a-4759-889f-b9848a59d79b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{destination}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="521136d0-a51f-4ca1-bdce-6d0ed1cd5c76"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{specialLoad} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="36b52f46-6f49-4c75-88d0-27a221bc62ec"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedBy}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="2cad93ef-d94f-4479-93e7-7a232023dace"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Submitted By:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="90474202-ce8b-4657-bad1-71edc8557335"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Phone:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="90" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="20d6f136-62e4-4332-9098-3355896ff4af"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phone}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
                <reportElement x="380" y="50" width="174" height="20" uuid="540bcba3-93ee-4877-b5a8-6f58db7c7398"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedAtDateTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="50" width="100" height="20" uuid="957ce926-9636-4625-b91f-78ecd3b8a200"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Submitted At:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="70" width="100" height="20" uuid="d8cf6e8b-9664-4012-b51d-6cdea49faf22"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Fax:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="70" width="174" height="20" uuid="cc95ebda-f955-4eaf-9314-45e4a56c4fde"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fax}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="554" height="50" uuid="f7c297a9-e14e-44de-8769-5d483cfe4863"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Consist for " + $F{railOperatorName} + " submitted by " + $F{submitter} + "\nConsist Location: " + $F{consistLocation}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-20" y="270" width="596" height="110" uuid="18015311-a28e-4eee-9051-45b1790d24f7">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreport runToBottom="true">
                    <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="50" y="60" width="130" height="20" uuid="4f470a33-ef93-425d-951e-e53642df7771">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{locoReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["locoSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="460" y="40" width="80" height="20" uuid="f182c7db-f00f-4107-bc33-93b30faf11a9">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="40" width="80" height="20" uuid="c5f34099-ac0e-4634-9398-a96f93c052f6">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesHauled}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="60" width="80" height="20" uuid="824478e7-fc00-4d16-8a39-6355baf4bc61">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Gross:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="40" width="80" height="20" uuid="e0bc266a-56f2-4246-bea6-f31c4718046d">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Hauled:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="60" width="80" height="20" uuid="74e9ef61-e6e0-45fa-9966-9950c2f5a1e0">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesGross}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="100" y="40" width="80" height="20" uuid="86833b59-3fe2-4c50-8d8e-18d80e082f75">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberOfVehicles}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="60" width="40" height="20" uuid="c08f0b3c-0ddf-4cbb-b377-1f48b80fa383">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Locos:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="40" width="90" height="20" uuid="6a4a5d4b-5762-45d2-b54f-2167af8da5f8">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Number Vehicles:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="0" width="551" height="35" uuid="53e5c946-8e6d-44fa-8715-f193d224b489">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="18"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Train Summary]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="370" y="40" width="80" height="20" uuid="31012f66-602d-4892-82f4-d1187915046e">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Total Length:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <subreport runToBottom="true">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="90" width="595" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="Group1" uuid="8e2dbcb5-3c3f-4bb5-a606-39f6f2e8656a">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["vehicleListSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="6" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="2" uuid="447d20b2-f65e-42ee-b2a8-69632882c668"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="1" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="24b6cb4b-7cad-4abd-a159-cc5cc11896db"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="533" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="5463547b-d0a6-440d-baa9-9b1dcce760bf"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="453" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="17310c63-a8e1-4f36-aad6-1b37346d27f6"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                    <reportElement style="Column header" x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="340aeee4-0582-45c2-9fbf-f1250cba3f8a"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I had to move the last subreport out of the frame so that it would render, but this seems to solve the problem of overlapping fields, and solve the problem introduced by user1791574's answer. However, that final subreport now appears on a whole new page, instead of splitting the data across pages, but I think that is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="X2010" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="25640552-4299-40b4-8655-a64e83b16458">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
<style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
<style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
<style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12"/>
<style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
        <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="trainNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="crewReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
<field name="trainType" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="origin" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="dangerousGoods" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="outOfGauge" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
<field name="trainDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="approvedLength" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="destination" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="specialLoad" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
<field name="submittedBy" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="phone" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="submittedAtDateTime" class="java.util.Date"/>
<field name="fax" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="numberOfVehicles" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="tonnesHauled" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="tonnesGross" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="totalLength" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="locoReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
<field name="vehicleReport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource"/>
<field name="railOperatorName" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="submitter" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="consistLocation" class="java.lang.String"/>
<group name="Group1">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/15)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<group name="Group2">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[(int)($V{REPORT_COUNT}/5)]]></groupExpression>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="107" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Title" x="80" y="0" width="472" height="62" uuid="b89a83c9-c1a2-4ab6-85a2-88ba23795dd3"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font pdfFontName="Times-Roman"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[X20.10 Report]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="5" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="1" y="1" width="552" height="2" uuid="f93f01ef-7224-41b8-a330-380bec4336d6"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="400" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="20c60332-1cff-4218-bfce-57cec3e447dd"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Train Number:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport runToBottom="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="220" width="595" height="45" uuid="4f24664e-5df0-4326-9b95-9939f93c48d4"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{crewReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["crewSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="120" width="90" height="20" uuid="110c9328-d33c-4c0a-86e5-7f4ebe669b4f"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="554" height="30" uuid="efaedffc-7d27-40f0-acc1-71797d91472c"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="18"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Train Details]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="91493735-ab12-4068-9583-9edbbac7ca35"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Train Type:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="a3e483b0-59c4-494c-ad36-1ea30eb4c5f5"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Origin]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="f5f23f73-3bdb-4b12-b9ec-d1946d1d249c"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Dangerous Goods:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="49aebc16-13db-4842-bb0f-23eac8f693a4"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Out of Gauge:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="140" width="90" height="20" uuid="ff7d87fc-1087-4edf-b1ed-454ff8ae94f8"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainType}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="160" width="90" height="20" uuid="7f109b0f-f4f4-48af-9a13-909b766dbd3c"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{origin}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="180" width="90" height="20" uuid="67f7fd28-1cee-402d-8a35-523058ab5061"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dangerousGoods} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="200" width="90" height="20" uuid="82586e0e-b6a7-43cf-9b1f-a12612396909"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{outOfGauge} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="94651700-a070-400e-a206-fd09170cf797"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Train Date:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
            <reportElement x="380" y="120" width="100" height="20" uuid="2ea29a18-1d85-4a23-b9f6-17459ceafe0d"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{trainDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="3ffe5495-6b91-424b-b652-c48c72b39a8f"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Approved Length:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="68bcc4c2-d6c0-426b-979c-c70bbd1c550c"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Destination:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="83e83257-d581-4fdd-8955-ef281357aaae"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Special Load:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="380" y="140" width="100" height="20" uuid="0f1b2cf0-73a3-4106-904a-8a28b7717909"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{approvedLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="380" y="160" width="100" height="20" uuid="7a006853-a10a-4759-889f-b9848a59d79b"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{destination}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="380" y="180" width="100" height="20" uuid="521136d0-a51f-4ca1-bdce-6d0ed1cd5c76"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{specialLoad} ? "Yes" : "No"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="36b52f46-6f49-4c75-88d0-27a221bc62ec"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedBy}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="90" height="20" uuid="2cad93ef-d94f-4479-93e7-7a232023dace"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Submitted By:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="90474202-ce8b-4657-bad1-71edc8557335"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Phone:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="90" y="70" width="90" height="20" uuid="20d6f136-62e4-4332-9098-3355896ff4af"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phone}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm">
            <reportElement x="380" y="50" width="174" height="20" uuid="540bcba3-93ee-4877-b5a8-6f58db7c7398"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{submittedAtDateTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="50" width="100" height="20" uuid="957ce926-9636-4625-b91f-78ecd3b8a200"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Submitted At:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="280" y="70" width="100" height="20" uuid="d8cf6e8b-9664-4012-b51d-6cdea49faf22"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Fax:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="380" y="70" width="174" height="20" uuid="cc95ebda-f955-4eaf-9314-45e4a56c4fde"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fax}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="554" height="50" uuid="f7c297a9-e14e-44de-8769-5d483cfe4863"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Consist for " + $F{railOperatorName} + " submitted by " + $F{submitter} + "\nConsist Location: " + $F{consistLocation}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport runToBottom="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="50" y="330" width="130" height="20" uuid="4f470a33-ef93-425d-951e-e53642df7771"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{locoReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["locoSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="460" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="f182c7db-f00f-4107-bc33-93b30faf11a9"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalLength}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="c5f34099-ac0e-4634-9398-a96f93c052f6"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesHauled}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="330" width="80" height="20" uuid="824478e7-fc00-4d16-8a39-6355baf4bc61"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Gross:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="190" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="e0bc266a-56f2-4246-bea6-f31c4718046d"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Tonnes Hauled:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField pattern="#0.00#;(#0.00#-)">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="280" y="330" width="80" height="20" uuid="74e9ef61-e6e0-45fa-9966-9950c2f5a1e0"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tonnesGross}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="100" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="86833b59-3fe2-4c50-8d8e-18d80e082f75"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberOfVehicles}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="330" width="40" height="20" uuid="c08f0b3c-0ddf-4cbb-b377-1f48b80fa383"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Locos:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="310" width="90" height="20" uuid="6a4a5d4b-5762-45d2-b54f-2167af8da5f8"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Number Vehicles:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="1" y="270" width="551" height="35" uuid="53e5c946-8e6d-44fa-8715-f193d224b489"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="18"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Train Summary]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="370" y="310" width="80" height="20" uuid="31012f66-602d-4892-82f4-d1187915046e"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Total Length:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport runToBottom="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="360" width="595" height="20" printWhenGroupChanges="Group1" uuid="8e2dbcb5-3c3f-4bb5-a606-39f6f2e8656a"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehicleReport}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["vehicleListSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="6" splitType="Stretch">
        <line>
            <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="0" width="554" height="2" uuid="447d20b2-f65e-42ee-b2a8-69632882c668"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#999999"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="1" width="597" height="24" forecolor="#D0B48E" backcolor="#F2EBDF" uuid="24b6cb4b-7cad-4abd-a159-cc5cc11896db"/>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="533" y="0" width="40" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="5463547b-d0a6-440d-baa9-9b1dcce760bf"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="453" y="0" width="80" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="17310c63-a8e1-4f36-aad6-1b37346d27f6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement style="Column header" x="22" y="1" width="197" height="20" forecolor="#736343" uuid="340aeee4-0582-45c2-9fbf-f1250cba3f8a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is causing an OutOfMemoryError with the message "GC overhead limit exceeded" when it tries to generate the first record. It is not getting to the point where it calls the next() method on my JRDataSource. When my version of the report is generated, it gets past that point quite quickly (but of course, has a broken layout).

Comment: Which version of iReport and jasper report are you using..,.

Comment: I'm using Jasper Reports version 5.2.0, and JasperSoft Studio 5.5.0 (not iReport, as iReport seems to no longer be supported).

Comment: You should choose same version of jasper report and jasper studio version, it may cause of conflict in your report.

Comment: Okay, I am now using version 5.5.1 of both the JasperReports library and JasperSoft Studio. After having to fiddle with the libraries included in my java programs to make them work again, I am still having the same problem if I set the position type of the elements under the subreport to Float.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError in not concern of jasper report. Please extend you jvm memory for application.

Comment: Okay, I have increased the memory of the program from 512MB to 1024MB. When I generate the report that I designed originally, multiple times, with only three records, it maxes out at 124MB, and garbage collection is able to bring that back down. The report design you suggested however, causes the program to use more and more memory until it finally crashes, even though I am using the exact same records for the report. Watching my logs, it is not getting past the first record in the report. I will post a graph that illustrates this soon.

Comment: Please refer to my edit above for a description of what is going on when I use your solution.

Comment: I had made just one change in report to set positionType as float. I am not sure what is your exact problem. At which programming language you are working with jasper report. Please share your working code with me so I will be able to resolve your problem. You can send me your application at this email id:
mabtestflight@gmail.com